# Update DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid`, which get his Data from a `ObservableCollection`.

my `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<CodeElement> _codeElementList;
public ObservableCollection<CodeElement> codeElementList
{
    get { return _codeElementList; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _codeElementList)
        {
            _codeElementList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("codeElementList");
        }
    }
}
```

I have test the `ObservableCollection` so too:

```
public ObservableCollection<CodeElement> codeElementList { get; set; }
```

the allocation

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            codeElementList = DBAnbindung.LoadCodeList();

            dtGCode.ItemsSource = codeElementList;
        }
```

The `ObservableCollection` get his data from a `database`. When i start the program, I can see all entries. Now i select a `codeElement` and delete it. The `codeElement` is deleted in the `database` but my `DataGrid` is empty.

```
            CodeElement code = dtGCode.SelectedItem as CodeElement;
            DBAnbindung.DeleteCode(code);
            codeElementList.Clear();
            codeElementList = DBAnbindung.LoadCodeList();
```

what am I doing wrong?
If you want to see how i load the `data` in my `ObservableCollection`, tell modest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to Add instead of assigning new list

```
codeElementList.AddRange(DBAnbindung.LoadCodeList());
```

**OR**

```
foreach(var item in DBAnbindung.LoadCodeList())
     codeElementList.Add(item);
```

Comment: thank you it works! my ObservableCollection have no Function "AddRange", but your secound way is very helpfull

Comment: Yes AddRange is Extension Method for ObservableCollection in Microsoft.Practices.Prism

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at this line

```
 codeElementList = DBAnbindung.LoadCodeList();
```

You are assigning another `ObservableCollection` to the `codeElementList` so  `dtGCode.ItemsSource` and the new `codeElementList` will not point to the same object in the memory. Then when you make changes to the `codeElementList` actually you are not changing the  `dtGCode.ItemsSource`.